# hyperdrive effect in canvas across randomly placed circles

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm trying to create a hyperdrive effect, like from Star Wars, where the stars have a motion trail. I've gotten as far as creating the motion trail on a single circle, it still looks like the trail is going down in the y direction and not forwards or positive in the z direction.

Also, how could I do this with (many) randomly placed circles as if they were stars?

My code is on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5m7x5zxu/) and below:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var xPos = 180;
var yPos = 100;

var motionTrailLength = 16;
var positions = [];

function storeLastPosition(xPos, yPos) {
  // push an item
  positions.push({
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  });

  //get rid of first item
  if (positions.length > motionTrailLength) {
    positions.pop();
  }
}
function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = positions.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    var ratio = (i - 1) / positions.length;
    drawCircle(positions[i].x, positions[i].y, ratio);
  }

  drawCircle(xPos, yPos, "source");
 var k=2;
  storeLastPosition(xPos, yPos);

  // update position
  if (yPos > 125) {
    positions.pop();
  }
  else{
    yPos += k*1.1;
   }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();


function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
  if (r == "source") {
    r = 1;
  } else {
    r*=1.1;
  }

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + parseFloat(1-r) + ")";
  context.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Canvas feedback and particles.

This type of FX can be done many ways.

You could just use a particle systems and draw stars (as lines) moving away from a central point, as the speed increase you increase the line length. When at low speed the line becomes a circle if you set `ctx.lineWidth > 1` and `ctx.lineCap = "round"`

To add to the FX you can use render feedback as I think you have done by rendering the canvas over its self. If you render it slightly larger you get a zoom FX. If you use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"` you can increase the stars intensity as you speed up to make up for the overall loss of brightness as stars move faster.

#### Example

I got carried away so you will have to sift through the code to find what you need.

The particle system uses the Point object and a special array called `bubbleArray` to stop GC hits from janking the animation.

You can use just an ordinary array if you want. The particles are independent of the bubble array. When they have moved outside the screen they are move to a pool and used again when a new particle is needed. The `update` function moves them and the `draw` Function draws them I guess LOL

The function `loop` is the main loop and adds and draws particles (I have set the particle count to 400 but should handle many more)

The hyper drive is operated via the mouse button. Press for on, let go for off. (It will distort the text if it's being displayed)

The canvas feedback is set via that `hyperSpeed` variable, the math is a little complex. The `sCurce` function just limits the value to 0,1 in this case to stop alpha from going over or under 1,0. The `hyperZero` is just the `sCurve` return for 1 which is the hyper drives slowest speed.

I have pushed the feedback very close to the limit. In the first few lines of the `loop` function you can set the top speed `if(mouse.button){ if(hyperSpeed < 1.75){` Over this value 1.75 and you will start to get bad FX, at about 2 the whole screen will just go white (I think that was where)

Just play with it and if you have questions ask in the comments.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// very simple mouse
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false} 
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));

// High performance array pool using buubleArray to separate pool objects and active object.
// This is designed to eliminate GC hits involved with particle systems and 
// objects that have short lifetimes but used often.
// Warning this code is not well tested.
const bubbleArray = () => {
    const items = [];
    var count = 0;
    return {
        clear(){  // warning this dereferences all locally held references and can incur Big GC hit. Use it wisely.
            this.items.length = 0;
            count = 0;
        },
        update() {
            var head, tail;
            head = tail = 0;
            while(head < count){
                if(items[head].update() === false) {head += 1 }
                else{
                    if(tail < head){
                        const temp = items[head];
                        items[head] = items[tail];
                        items[tail] = temp;
                    }
                    head += 1;
                    tail += 1;
                }
            }
            return count = tail;
        },
        createCallFunction(name, earlyExit = false){
            name = name.split(" ")[0];
            const keys = Object.keys(this);
            if(Object.keys(this).indexOf(name) > -1){  throw new Error(`Can not create function name '${name}' as it already exists.`) }
            if(!/\W/g.test(name)){
                let func;
                if(earlyExit){
                    func = `var items = this.items; var count = this.getCount(); var i = 0;\nwhile(i < count){ if (items[i++].${name}() === true) { break } }`;
                }else{
                    func = `var items = this.items; var count = this.getCount(); var i = 0;\nwhile(i < count){ items[i++].${name}() }`;
                }
                !this.items && (this.items = items);
                this[name] = new Function(func);
            }else{  throw new Error(`Function name '${name}' contains illegal characters. Use alpha numeric characters.`) }
            
        },
        callEach(name){var i = 0; while(i < count){ if (items[i++][name]() === true) { break } } },
        each(cb) { var i = 0; while(i < count){ if (cb(items[i], i++) === true) { break } } },
        next() { if (count < items.length) { return items[count ++] } },
        add(item) {
            if(count === items.length){
                items.push(item);
                count ++;
            }else{
                items.push(items[count]);
                items[count++] = item;
            }
            return item;
        },
        getCount() { return count },
    }
}

// Helpers rand float, randI random Int
// doFor iterator
// sCurve curve input -Infinity to Infinity out -1 to 1
// randHSLA creates random colour
// CImage, CImageCtx create image and image with context attached
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand  = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); }; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove

const sCurve = (v,p) => (2 / (1 + Math.pow(p,-v))) -1;
const randHSLA = (h, h1, s = 100, s1 = 100, l = 50, l1 = 50, a = 1, a1 = 1) => { return `hsla(${randI(h,h1) % 360},${randI(s,s1)}%,${randI(l,l1)}%,${rand(a,a1)})` }
const CImage = (w = 128, h = w) => (c = document.createElement("canvas"),c.width = w,c.height = h, c);
const CImageCtx = (w = 128, h = w) => (c = CImage(w,h), c.ctx = c.getContext("2d"), c);

// create image to hold text
var textImage = CImageCtx(1024, 1024);
var c = textImage.ctx;
c.fillStyle = "#FF0";
c.font = "64px arial black";
c.textAlign = "center";
c.textBaseline = "middle";
const text = "HYPER,SPEED FX,VII,,Battle of Jank,,Hold the mouse,button to increase,speed.".split(",");
text.forEach((line,i) => { c.fillText(line,512,i * 68 + 68) });
const maxLines = text.length * 68 + 68;
function starWarIntro(image,x1,y1,x2,y2,pos){
  var iw = image.width;
  var ih = image.height;
  var hh = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);      // Slope of left edge
  var w2 = iw / 2;                      // half width
  var z1 = w2 - x1;                    // Distance (z) to first line
  var z2 = (z1 / (w2 - x2)) * z1 - z1; // distance (z) between first and last line
  var sk,t3,t3a,z3a,lines, z3, dd = 0, a = 0, as = 2 / (y2 - y1);
  for (var y = y1; y < y2 && dd < maxLines; y++) {      // for each line

      t3 = ((y - y1) * hh) + x1;       // get scan line top left edge
      t3a = (((y+1) - y1) * hh) + x1;  // get scan line bottom left edge
      z3 = (z1 / (w2 - t3)) * z1;      // get Z distance to top of this line
      z3a = (z1 / (w2 - t3a)) * z1;      // get Z distance to bottom of this line
      dd = ((z3 - z1) / z2) * ih;       // get y bitmap coord
      a += as;

      ctx.globalAlpha = a < 1 ? a : 1;
      dd += pos;                         // kludge for this answer to make text move
                                         // does not move text correctly 
      lines = ((z3a - z1) / z2) * ih-dd;       // get number of lines to copy
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, dd , iw, lines, t3, y, w - t3 * 2, 1.5);
  }
}


// canvas settings
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
// diagonal distance used to set point alpha (see point update)
var diag = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
// If window size is changed this is called to resize the canvas
// It is not called via the resize event as that can fire to often and
// debounce makes it feel sluggish so is called from main loop.
function resizeCanvas(){
  points.clear();
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  cw = w / 2;  // center 
  ch = h / 2;
  diag = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
  
}
// create array of points
const points = bubbleArray(); 
// create optimised draw function itterator
points.createCallFunction("draw",false);
// spawns a new star
function spawnPoint(pos){
    var p = points.next();
    p = points.add(new  Point())    
    if (p === undefined) { p = points.add(new  Point()) }
    p.reset(pos);  
}
// point object represents a single star
function Point(pos){  // this function is duplicated as reset 
    if(pos){
        this.x = pos.x;   
        this.y = pos.y;   
        this.dead = false;
    }else{
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.dead = true;
    }
    this.alpha = 0;
    var x = this.x - cw;
    var y = this.y - ch;
    this.dir = Math.atan2(y,x);
    this.distStart = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    this.speed = rand(0.01,1);
    this.col = randHSLA(220,280,100,100,50,100);
    this.dx = Math.cos(this.dir) * this.speed;
    this.dy = Math.sin(this.dir) * this.speed;
}
Point.prototype = {
    reset : Point,  // resets the point
    update(){       // moves point and returns false when outside 
        this.speed *= hyperSpeed;  // increase speed the more it has moved
        this.x += Math.cos(this.dir) * this.speed;
        this.y += Math.sin(this.dir) * this.speed;
        var x = this.x - cw;
        var y = this.y - ch;
        this.alpha = (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) - this.distStart) / (diag * 0.5 - this.distStart);
        if(this.alpha > 1 || this.x < 0 || this.y < 0 || this.x > w || this.h > h){
           this.dead = true;
        }
        return !this.dead;
    },
    draw(){  // draws the point 
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.col;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.25 + this.alpha *0.75;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(this.x - this.dx * this.speed, this.y - this.dy * this.speed);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
}

const maxStarCount = 400;
const p = {x : 0, y : 0};
var hyperSpeed = 1.001;
const alphaZero = sCurve(1,2);
var startTime;
function loop(time){

    if(startTime === undefined){
        startTime = time;
    }
    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
       resizeCanvas();
    }
    // if mouse down then go to hyper speed
    if(mouse.button){
        if(hyperSpeed < 1.75){
            hyperSpeed += 0.01;
        }
    }else{
        if(hyperSpeed > 1.01){
            hyperSpeed -= 0.01;
        }else if(hyperSpeed > 1.001){
            hyperSpeed -= 0.001;
        }
    }
    
    var hs = sCurve(hyperSpeed,2);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform


    //==============================================================
    // UPDATE the line below could be the problem. Remove it and try
    // what is under that        
    //==============================================================
    //ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(0,0,0,${1-(hs-alphaZero)*2})`;
    
    // next two lines are the replacement
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1-(hs-alphaZero) * 2;
    //==============================================================



    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    // the amount to expand canvas feedback
    var sx = (hyperSpeed-1) * cw * 0.1;
    var sy = (hyperSpeed-1) * ch * 0.1;

    // increase alpha as speed increases
    ctx.globalAlpha = (hs-alphaZero)*2;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    // draws feedback twice
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,-sx, -sy, w + sx*2 , h + sy*2)
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,-sx/2, -sy/2, w + sx , h + sy)
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    
    // add stars if count < maxStarCount 
    if(points.getCount() < maxStarCount){
        var cent = (hyperSpeed - 1) *0.5; // pulls stars to center as speed increases
        doFor(10,()=>{
            p.x = rand(cw * cent ,w - cw * cent);  // random screen position
            p.y = rand(ch * cent,h - ch * cent);
            spawnPoint(p)
            
        })
    }
    // as speed increases make lines thicker
    ctx.lineWidth = 2 + hs*2;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    points.update();  // update points
    points.draw();     // draw points
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    // scroll the perspective star wars text FX
    var scrollTime = (time - startTime) / 5 - 2312;
    if(scrollTime < 1024){
        starWarIntro(textImage,cw - h * 0.5, h * 0.2, cw - h * 3, h , scrollTime );
    }
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I searched for minutes and couldn't find Coruscant in there... Is this a bug? Really nice, even though it's quite far from OP's code (and maybe current level?)

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, :) Like i said in the answer I got carried away. The OP should be able to get some usefull stuff from it, I have been adding comments in the code as it is hard to explain in just words how to achieve these types of FX.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. I appreciate what you wrote and hope it serves the community well. It is beyond my level because I have never used canvas before. Granted, I've seen some amazing examples of first time canvas attempts. Anyway, thank you. I very simply developed it further for touch support and I thought I broke it, but now that I run this example on the same machine, the bug I am getting is that by default on load, everything from the text to the stars has a motion trail that goes on forever as it goes into the horizion. mouse.button is false and no mouse or touch events are firing.

Comment: @Blindman67 I can't seem to figure out why this only happens sometimes in the same exact environment (latest chrome). Here is the code with the touch events: http://eightar.ms/, here is your exact example: http://eightar.ms/original/, and here is a screenshot of what I am seeing (with my edited code): http://eightar.ms/bug1/ and the original code: http://eightar.ms/bug2/

Comment: @wordSmith Making a guess... The reason could be the line `ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,${1-(hs-alphaZero)*2})';` The comment section does not let me show the correct quotes, but it is a template string and I am not 100% sure of its compatibility. I have updated the answer's example code with an alternative, see if that helps, if not I would need the the browser , and device on which it is happening to try and solve. The problem is most definitely that the screen is not clearing correctly.

Comment: @Blindman67 I believe I updated the code correctly and it is still happening. The above links to the live pages are updated with the code, but the issue persists. Wasn't always like this, but after I updated to the latest Mac OS High Sierra. Running Chrome 60. Does not happen when I set mouse.button=false programmatically or trigger a mouseup, touchend, or pointerup event, which of course sets the coords and mouse.button to false

Comment: @wordSmith . Make sure you  cleared  cache for the change to work, server is not marking the page changed. Try clamping alpha `ctx.globalAlpha = Math.max(0.1,Math.min(1,1-(hs-alphaZero)*2));` the 2nd line in change. If not work. just set  `ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;`  and if still not work then change line below from  `ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h)` to `ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);` to make sure the globals are not getting clobbered. Or try `else { hyperSpeed = 1.002}`in main  loop after the else that does  `hyperSpeed -= 0.001`  as that could let a bad val through.

Comment: @wordSmith I will have to have another look if none of that works, but for now I am pushed for time.

Comment: @Blindman67 So the only solution that somewhat worked was ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5, but then on mousedown, touchstart, pointerdown the motion trails blurred together and large areas into an interesting/trippy yet different, undesired effect. I noticed the first edit works fine on the events, but not on load so I only set the globalAlpha to 0.5 when mouse.button is false. Works great everywhere I test it now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple example, based mainly on the same idea as Blindman67, concetric lines moving away from center at different velocities (the farther from center, the faster it moves..) also no recycling pool here.

```js
 "use strict"
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(c);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var ox = w / 2;
var oy = h / 2;
c.width = w; c.height = h;

const stars = 120;
const speed = 0.5;
const trailLength = 90; 

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff"
ctx.fillRect(ox, oy, 1, 1);

init();

function init() {
 var X = [];
 var Y = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < stars; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * w;
  var y = Math.random() * h;
  X.push( translateX(x) );
  Y.push( translateY(y) );
 }
 drawTrails(X, Y)
}

function translateX(x) {
 return x - ox;
}

function translateY(y) {
 return oy - y;
}

function getDistance(x, y) {
 return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

function getLineEquation(x, y) {
 return function(n) {
   return y / x * n;
  }
}

function drawTrails(X, Y) {
 var count = 1;
 ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
 function anim() {
  for(var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
   var x = X[i];
   var y = Y[i];
   drawNextPoint(x, y, count);
  }
  count+= speed;
  if(count < trailLength) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
  else {
   init();
  }
 }
 anim();
}

function drawNextPoint(x, y, step) {
 ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
 var f = getLineEquation(x, y);
 var coef = Math.abs(x) / 100;
 var dist = getDistance( x, y);
 var sp = speed * dist / 100;
 for(var i = 0; i < sp; i++) {
  var newX = x + Math.sign(x) * (step + i) * coef;
  var newY = translateY( f(newX) );
  ctx.fillRect(newX + ox, newY, 1, 1);
 }

}
```

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```